# Error while generating an Excel file

Tags: php, phpexcel

I use the library PHPExcel for generating ".xlsx" files. The file is generated, but when I try to open it I get an error: `Excel found some unreadable content. Do you want to fix the content?` When I click on "yes" it opens my file with the content I want.

How can I avoid this error? I've already deleted all the spaces after the `<?php ?>` tags, I've already checked that I don't have HTML before the file is generated, but I still don't know where my error is.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include ('/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php');
include ('/lib/PHPExcel/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

// I use session for now when the excel is generate       
$_SESSION['downloadstatus'] = array(
    "status" => "pending"
);

// Creation of the Excel File
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()
            ->setCreator("Temporaris")
            ->setLastModifiedBy("Temporaris")
            ->setTitle("Template Relevé des heures intérimaires")
            ->setSubject("Template excel")
            ->setDescription("Template excel permettant la création d'un ou plusieurs relevés d'heures")
            ->setKeywords("Template excel");
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

// Add the content of Excel File
$indiceColumn = "A";
$indiceLine = 1;

$defaultColumns = array("Matricule", "Nom_Prenom", "Siret_etablissement", "Regate_etablissement", "Centre_analytique", "Date");
foreach ($defaultColumns as $columnName) {
    $sheet->SetCellValue($indiceColumn . $indiceLine, $columnName);
    $indiceColumn++;
}

$listColumnName = EDIXIS_db_query("select csv_nom_col FROM  temporaris_eu_config_ent_csv WHERE id_config = " . $id_sel . " ORDER BY id");
while ($columnName = EDIXIS_db_fetch_object($listColumnName)) {
    $sheet->SetCellValue($indiceColumn . $indiceLine, $columnName->csv_nom_col);
    $indiceColumn++;
}

// Send the Excel File to the user
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="template.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save('php://output');
$_SESSION['downloadstatus'] = array(
    "status"  => "finished",
    "message" => "Done"
);
?>
```

----- Edit -----

I try to check the difference between a repair file and the error file so i open them with notpad++.

Their is some caracters who are differents between the error file and the repair file :

- some • who became «
- some " who became « too
- This line

`‚›.›”Ò© +@SdÕ Eë Ý²äÄfÃH*²?ÙÑý®³+ @ îå¹œá¨½]YC^!&íÝŒVSN    8é•v‹}œßOn(IY8%Œw0£kHô¶{×ÊÐHá{ôbÖ‚\jd˜ÑeÎ¡a,É%X‘¦èp(>ûhEÆe\° ä‹X «9ÿÄ,d¡DlNÂHwH%ÈÐGS J20`ÁåÄªiÅŽÞÑ¦77åÄiu^xÓºîUÒã0ÓáºXñüûõðíg)u¢ÝØ* ´k•ld‘}ìæ`ƒ"êÔ²“ÏcHù›ý¬A}YŸ9/ÕvWÜ– Šà¡šm    {åéúîëüžv5¯>N8>æüsSó¦®¯xÝp>žàr¤Ú]Òÿa÷”Ò¬³R•Á,ò¯ìuCËúˆ/íò&j+4.Js¶;Æ½è’Q‡Œsy$ÀJ‚!883ØéLŒ 2nÄè"ê}ïˆïI0}ÒÈO$–À„Ê6¯Dœ‚Ç Ôÿþ2ÿR¬{i¼ªX>ªtá;ÕÊoÚÂG¼/v¹:ûeº¿PK    ”J¤Fs‘{Y³  ¦     xl/theme/theme1.xmlíYOoÛ6¿ïSº·²lÉu‚:EìØëÖ¦`

who became this line

`Ë7\ ÖIDiV´W¬„ +¸5ölkÖ;›ö‘ûLÜºwH‘"çÇ3ž´·kgÙ3`2ÁÏy=­8¯‚6~9ç‹»ÉÎR–^K<Ìù¿í^µ*6* |Ã³ÄäS£âœ¯rŽI­ÀÉ4%‡'ñ1 “™–¸Qª'¹1«ª÷ÂA–Zf)Fà$‰|ÔêˆŒ=ÚÐJ€>'QOkqòf@—^ÜP”3§3yáEëA<º×ÉÃ0L‡›b¥ó×â×ý×¥Ô‰ñc«ð®ÕªQ2ìàb@‰&µâìóØB+S¾§f?ÐŸ6ÎkµÝ·#€ft¨fWÂAùyóùËâŽw³ª~7©èy»¨>6³º©goªYSUã . 'ªÛ'ýö@)È&[(UYÊbßéÊž·LÓ°¬ GzŸ·hœ4´(ÍÙí÷’K¡‰™æòD€µËh>hf¨Ó™YÉnåèbúuïYèY´}2ÄOK`"e—W"ÎÁcPêÿ•ÿ )Öƒ4^Õl†€:]ùÎµò[¶H÷%®W¿L÷PK    «J¤Fs‘{Y³  ¦     xl/theme/theme1.xmlíYOoÛ6¿ïSº·²lÉu‚:EìØëÖ¦`

So i think it's an encode problem. But i still don't know  how can i resolve it.

Comment: Standard comment in this situation.... open file in a text editor and look for leading/trailing whitespace, BOM header, any plaintext messages echoed by your code into the php://output stream.... once you've found any of those, fix them, dirty workround is to use ob_end_clean() before the save

Comment: As a test, try saving to a file on the webserver rather than php://output, and see if that file is readable by Excel

Comment: When i try to save it as file on server i still have the problem and when i open the file with notpad++ i don't find anything readeable except [Content_Types].xml but it's normal if my memory is good

Comment: If Excel is complaining about unreadable content, then there's normally something that has been injected into the file from somewhere.... but if you have that problem when saving the file to a server, then it's possible that you've found a bug in PHPExcel, though with such a simple script, it's hard to imagine that could have caused a corruption..... how many entries are being selected from your csv_nom_col table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the problem it was so stupid. It's just that it's not allow to put some specials characters in `$objPHPExcel->getProperties()` so i replace every 'é' by 'e'  and now it's work.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is your $_SESSION code at the end.

```
$_SESSION['downloadstatus'] = array(
    "status"  => "finished",
    "message" => "Done"
);
```

Since the headers have already been output, I'm almost certain you are getting a php warning appended to the end of your excel document. Make the following changes and it should work.

```
$_SESSION['downloadstatus'] = array(
    "status"  => "finished",
    "message" => "Done"
);

// Send the Excel File to the user
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="template.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
$writer->save('php://output');
exit;
```

Comment: I try your solution but it's don't work and i check in my log file of php and nothing appear when i launch the script.